# Segmentation Fault in while loop (C)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm writing a program to convert base-10 numbers into their equivalents in other bases, but I keep getting a segmentation fault when I try to run it.

This is the code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int base;
int num;
char* num2[50];
int x =0;

int main(){

    printf("Input a number in base 10 and a base (2-16) that you would like to convert to in this format: 100 2\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d%d",&num, &base);
    printf("%d%d", num, base); fflush(stdout);

    while ((num % base) > 1){
        printf("%d", x); fflush(stdout);
        if(num % base == 10)
            num2[x] = "A";
        else if (num % base == 11)
            num2[x] = "B";
        else if (num % base == 12)
            num2[x] = "C";
        else if (num % base == 13)
            num2[x] = "D";
        else if (num % base == 14)
            num2[x] = "E";
        else if (num % base == 15)
            num2[x] = "F";
        else
            *num2[x] = num % base;

        num = num % base;
        x++;
        printf("%d, %s", num, num2[x]); fflush(stdout);
    }

    while (x >= 0){
        printf("%s", num2[1]);
        fflush(stdout);
        x--;
    }

    printf("\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    return 0;
}
```

Through checking the errors with gdb and print statements, I've come to the conclusion that the error stems from something in line 14:

```
while ((num % base) > 1) {
```

I'm relatively new to C, most of what I've done has been in Java.

Comment: You need to learn how to use GDB better since your diagnosis misses the mark by a lot. http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~adnan/gdb-refcard.pdf

Comment: I'm a student and it's only been briefly discussed in my class. Thanks for the ref card, that'll definitely come in handy in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the earlier answers are right (i.e. @Sourav and @Tony).
The exact reason among these 2 depends on the input provided during an execution instance.

1. Say, your input is num=3, base=16.
   Then, your program will crash at the line -
   `*num2[x] = num % base;`

   num2[x] points to NULL since 'num2' is a global array.
2. Say, your input is num=13, base=16.
   Then, your program will crash at the line -
   `num2[x] = "D";`

   This is because 'num' remains a constant at 13 (`num = num % base`) and as a result 'x' would eventually be a value way beyond 49 and `num2[x]` will be accessing an illegal location.

---

Also, your program is logically flawed; you will not get the output that you desire with your current approach. Your program needs to be tweaked slightly -

```
char num2[50]; /* Array of chars, instead of array of pointers to char. */
```

.
.
.

```
/* Add check to verify that base is a value between 2 and 16. */

while ((num % base) > 0){  /* Greater than 0, not 1. */
    if(num % base == 10)
        num2[x] = 'A'; /* Use a character instead of a string. */
    else if (num % base == 11)
        num2[x] = 'B';
    else if (num % base == 12)
        num2[x] = 'C';
    else if (num % base == 13)
        num2[x] = 'D';
    else if (num % base == 14)
        num2[x] = 'E';
    else if (num % base == 15)
        num2[x] = 'F';
    else
        num2[x] = (num % base) + '0'; /* Convert the number to its character form. */

    num /= base;  /* Duh! */
    printf("%d, %c", num, num2[x]); fflush(stdout); /* %c instead of %s*/
    x++;
}

while (x >= 0){
    printf("%c", num2[x]); fflush(stdout);  /* %c instead of %s*/
    x--;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! My reasoning was that I'd fix my logic after I fixed the error, since then I could use test values, etc.

Comment: If this solved your problem accept the answer; optionally upvote.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as I see it is in the `else` statement body,

```
else
  *num2[x] = num % base;
```

here, `num[x]` is a null pointer. You cannot dereference that. You need to allocate memory to `num[x]` before you can use that location to *store* some value.